# How to configure PhpStorm, Codeception and Docker to reliably get code coverage

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, code-coverage, codeception

I can not figure out how to *reliably* configure the parts of my project to get code coverage displayed in PhpStorm.

I am using PhpStorm (EAP), docker (`19.03.5-rc1`) and docker-compose (`1.24.1`). I set up my project with a docker-compose.yml that includes a php service (Docker image `in2code/php-dev:7.3-fpm` which includes xdebug and is based on the official `php:7.3-fpm` image)
I created a new project with composer and required codeception (`3.1.2`). I ran the codecption bootstrap, added the coverage settings, created a unit test and ran the while tests suite with coverage. The coverage does not appear in PhpStorm or it does show 0% everywhere. I can not figure out how to configure PhpStorm/Codeception to show the coverage. There are Projects where this works but they are configured to use a Docker image instead of a running docker-compose container.

I tried following remote PHP interpreters:

- Remote PHP Interpreter -> Docker -> Image (`in2code/php-dev:7.3-fpm`)
- Remote PHP Interpreter -> Docker -> Image built by docker-compose for this project (`cct_php:latest`)
- Remote PHP Interpreter -> Docker Compose -> service php -> docker-compose exec
- Remote PHP Interpreter -> Docker Compose -> service php -> docker-compose run

I created a PHP Test Framework for each interpreter i created above.
I created a Codeception run confgiguration for each Test Framework configuration.
I executed all Codeception run configurations with any combination of (Project Default) PHP CLI Interpreter and other remote interpreters.

The Testing Framework is configured with the correct path to codeception (codeception version is detected by phpstorm) and it holds the path to the codeception.yml file as default configuration file. All run configurations are using the default configuration file from the test framework configuration.

I also tried to enable coverage in the root codeception.yml file, tried `work_dir: /app` and `remote: false`.

None of these attempts generated a code coverage that was displayed in PhpStorm.

Projects where code coverage works are configured with PHP Remote Interpreter Docker Image (docker-compose built image for that project)
Edit: The CLI Interpreter for the project must be the image built by `docker-compose build`. Setting different Command Line interpreters in the Codeception run configuration does not have any effects

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  php:
    image: in2code/php-dev:7.3-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
      - $HOME/.composer/auth.json:/tmp/composer/auth.json
      - $HOME/.composer/cache/:/tmp/composer/cache/
```

tests/unit.suite.yml

```
actor: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Asserts
        - \App\Tests\Helper\Unit
    step_decorators: ~

coverage:
    enable: true
    remote: true
    include:
        - src/*
```

tests/unit/App/Controller/AirplaneControllerTest.php

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Tests\App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AirplaneController;

class AirplaneControllerTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    /**
     * @covers \App\Controller\AirplaneController::start
     */
    public function testSomeFeature()
    {
        $airplaneController = new AirplaneController();
        $airplaneController->start();
    }
}
```

Did i miss something in my configuration?
The best solution would be a valid configuration using `docker-compose exec` for the remote interpreter, so other services like mysql or ldap are available for functional tests.

Comment: [Rutger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3316739) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68701996) saying "Have a look at the workaround described here: [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-61914](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-61914)"

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's hopelessly broken at the moment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32625

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that PHPStorm calls codeception with this option

`--coverage-xml /opt/phpstorm-coverage/admin_service$unit_tests.xml`

but when testing is done I get this message

`XML report generated in /opt/phpstorm-coverage/admin_service$$unit_tests.xml`

Notice the filename is different. So I've created a link using this command

`ln admin_service\$\$unit_tests.xml admin_service\$unit_tests.xml`

and restarted the test coverage. The coverage window showed up.